# Py to exe error (ImportError: OpenCV loader: missing configuration file: ['config.py']. Check OpenCV installation)

Tags: python, tkinter

**Use open cv for qr reading
if i try to converting exe i face some errors**

`def qrread():
import cv2
import os
import ast
from datetime import datetime

```
# initalize the cam
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
# initialize the cv2 QRCode detector
detector = cv2.QRCodeDetector()
while True:
    _, img = cap.read()
    # detect and decode
    data, bbox, _ = detector.detectAndDecode(img)
    # check if there is a QRCode in the image
    if data:
        a=data
        break
    # display the result
    cv2.imshow("QRCODEscanner", img)    
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord("q"):
        break


`[After the coverting py to exe i face this error (ImportError: OpenCV loader: missing configuration file: ['config.py']. Check OpenCV installation.)][1]
```

Comment: Please post more information: what you used for exe, source code where the error is raised, etc.

Comment: Please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for the community to know and understand what’s the problem and if the problem is in the code.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what this has to do with `tkinter`. Why did you add  the [tag:tkinter] tag?